# Wordpress orderby custom field and date not working

Tags: wordpress

i'm trying to do the following:

Edit the main query via `pre_get_posts` and set a custom field (meta) and the creation date as orderby arguments. The query works well but only for the first argument in `orderby`. The second is completely ignored.

```
$query->set('meta_key', 'm_sticky');
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value, date);
$query->set('order', 'DESC, DESC');
```

The output should be:

First items:
Posts who have set the `meta_value` to 1 and ordered by date

Second items:
Posts who have set the `meta_value` to 0 and ordere by date

Comment: You missed a closing quote sign (') on the second line: `'meta_value, date` - is that a typo or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the 1/0 isn't bolean.

See if this works:

```
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num', date);

$query->set('order', 'ASC, DESC');
```